# Scope css build in vite build

Tags: vue.js, vite

Anybody know if it's possible to `scope` the style to avoid leak in a vue app that are integrated in a php application.
I use this `vite.config.ts` to have a single `index.js` in output:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Components({ resolvers: [PuikResolver()] }),
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin()
  ],
  server: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
})
```